# R Shiny warning message when wrong file is uploaded

Tags: r, csv, file-upload, shiny, rstudio

I want to have a feature in my shiny app that when someone uploads a file which is not in .csv format they recieve a warning and when they do upload in .csv format it prints the table. here is my UI code

```
shinyUI(
tabPanel("File Upload",
                      h4("File Upload"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV file to upload',
                                    accept = c(
                                      'text/csv',
                                      'text/comma-separated-values',
                                      'text/tab-separated-values',
                                      'text/plain',
                                      '.csv',
                                      '.tsv'
                                    )
                          )
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tableOutput('upload'),
                          h1(textOutput("warning1"))
                          )


                      )

               )
)
```

and my Server code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$upload <- renderTable({


  #assign uploaded file to a variable
  File <- input$file1

  #catches null exception
  if (is.null(File))
    return(NULL)

  read.csv(File$datapath)

})

output$warning1 <- renderPrint({

  upload<- input$file1
  if (is.null(upload))
    return(NULL)

  if (upload$type != c(
                          'text/csv',
                          'text/comma-separated-values',
                          'text/tab-separated-values',
                          'text/plain',
                          '.csv',
                          '.tsv'
                        )    
      )
  return ("Wrong File Format try again!")


})


}
```

Comment: So what is the problem and what is the error you get?

Comment: My problem is that it doesn't seem to ever catch the correct file type. It prints every format even if it isn't csv format. The $type doesn't seem to work and sends an empty value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need is a `validate` statement.  Also, you would need to use the `%in%` function to check if a value is in a vector, just FYI.  The following is a much simpler implementation for your warning/error.  It utilizes the `file_ext` function from the `tools` package.

```
library(shiny)
library(tools)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = tabPanel("File Upload",
               h4("File Upload"),
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV file to upload',
                             accept = c(
                               'text/csv',
                               'text/comma-separated-values',
                               'text/tab-separated-values',
                               'text/plain',
                               'csv',
                               'tsv'
                             )
                   )
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   tableOutput('upload')
                 )
               )

      ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$upload <- renderTable({

        #assign uploaded file to a variable
        File <- input$file1        

        #catches null exception
        if (is.null(File))
          return(NULL)

        validate(
          need(file_ext(File$name) %in% c(
            'text/csv',
            'text/comma-separated-values',
            'text/tab-separated-values',
            'text/plain',
            'csv',
            'tsv'
          ), "Wrong File Format try again!"))

        read.csv(File$datapath)
      })
    }
    ))
```