# How can I create a pop-up window in Shiny to warn user about selecting one type of file extension?

Tags: javascript, r, csv, shiny, popup

I need to have a pop-up window for when the uploaded file is not .csv file. The window information can be like "The .csv as file extension is allowed to be uploaded!". Unfortunately, I couldn't succeed in creating a pop-up window in Shiny so the code provided looks quite basic:

```
  library(shiny)

   shinyUI(
     fluidPage(
      fileInput("file1",
          "Choose CSV files from directory",
          multiple = TRUE,
          accept=c('text/csv', 
                   'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                   '.csv')),
      dataTableOutput("importcsv")))
```

## server.R

```
  library(shiny)

   shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$importcsv <- renderDataTable({

     filecsv <- input$file1
     if (is.null(filecsv)) {
     return(NULL)
     } else {
      filecsv %>%
        rowwise() %>%
       do({
        read.csv(.$datapath)
       })
      }
     }) 

     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactive text is pretty simple (although you need to test the filetype). Try

```
# ui.R    
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fileInput("file1",
              "Choose CSV files from directory",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept=c('text/csv', 
                       'text/comma-separated-values',
                       'text/plain', 
                       '.csv')),
    htmlOutput('filetype'),
    dataTableOutput("importcsv")))
```

and

```
# server.R
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$importcsv <- renderDataTable({
    filecsv <- input$file1
    if (is.null(filecsv)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      output$filetype <- renderText({
        ifelse(input$file1$type %in% c('text/csv', 
                               'text/comma-separated-values',
                               'text/plain', 
                               '.csv'), 
               '', 
               HTML('<script type="text/javascript">alert("CSV, please!");</script>'))
           })
      filecsv %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        do({
          read.csv(.$datapath)
        })
    }
  })  
})
```

That lets you show a string in your UI dependent on the filetype. Then you need to format your string. Shiny supports some HTML text tags (`p`, `h1` to `h6`, etc.), but to get a popup, you need to call JavaScript.

The above code wraps the JavaScript alert in an HTML `<script>` tag, all in an R string, all wrapped in a Shiny `HTML()` function to keep it from being treated as escaped display text. It's a double turducken, but it works, and is surprisingly intelligible. It doesn't stop the the datatable from rendering, but you could easily rearrange it to do so (a good idea, as `fileInput` smashes *everything* into a dataframe, regardless of filetype).

A look at R's error handling is probably in order here, too. See `?try` and `?tryCatch`. And careful of security; that's not my area, but I suspect this would be iffy deployed for real.

Comment: See [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022770/r-shiny-warning-message-when-wrong-file-is-uploaded?rq=1); validating is probably what you want to do anyway, but I read your question pretty literally.

Comment: when i compare the "similar" example with mine, the pop-up window is needed to show the warnings. And it works nice. thank for your helping! :)

Comment: I happened across [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452465/how-to-create-textarea-as-input-in-a-shiny-webapp-in-r) today, which led me to think that if you like, you could rewrite the line with the JavaScript as `tags$script(type = "text/javascript", 'alert("CSV, please!");')` which is probably slightly more robust.

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing that the pop window does not appear when i try to uplaod pdf file? how can i develop?

Comment: It's because you're passing the file to `renderDataTable` regardless of whether it's a .csv. When passed a .pdf, it raises an AJAX error (you'd have to dig into the source code to figure out why) which stops the execution of `renderDataTable`, which includes the alert code. Really, there's no reason to render anything that's not a .csv, though, so you can solve the issue by putting the `filetype %>% ...` chain in a conditional: `if(input$file1$type %in% c('text/csv', ... )) { filetype %>% ... }` so it only renders if the file is a .csv.